# Convert x digit number into two digit number

Tags: python

I am currently having x number in a list, and I am trying to convert inconsistent data that may be in 1 digit, 5 digit or 2 digit.

How can I convert all into 2 digit number?

Example:

```
def List_Convert_2_Digit(z):
    for i in range(len(z)):
        while(z[i]<100 or z[i]>10):
            if(z[i]<100):
                z[i]=z[i]/10
            else:
                z[i]=z[i]*10
    return z

list_a = [5.2,1600,520,3600,13,55,4000]

result_list= List_Convert_2_Digit(list_a)
```

Result should yields: [52,16,52,36,13,55,40]

But the above code does not work and it's running forever.

I've tried mod, but it is not what I am looking for.

Comment: What is the algorithm (in words or pseudocode) supposed to be for converting a multi-digit number into a 2-digit one?

Comment: What should a 1-digit number be in 2-digit format?
1 => 01 or 1 => 1

Comment: It should be 10

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you just want to take the first two characters from each, and if there is a separator (dot in your case) ignore it.

In that case you can do this:

```
two_digit_list = [int(str(x).replace('.', '')[:2]) for x in List]
```

If other non numeric characters than a dot are going to appear your would have to deal with those as well of course :)

What this does is just converts the numbers to a string, removes dots and then grabs the first two characters and converts it back to an int.

EDIT: Since I saw you replied to someone above that single digit numbers should have 0 added to the end you can do this instead to cover that case:

```
two_digit_list = [int(str(x).replace('.', '')[:2]) if len(str(x).replace('.', '')) > 1 else int(f"{x}0") for x in List]
```

At that point it's a bit too long to be a pretty list comprehension so you could always just break it up into a for loop if it's unclear, might be a good exercise if nothing else :)

Comment: I've edited a bit, with a for a loop because it should be List[0] should yield 52 but yours yields 00, but you are a lifesaver! Thank you

Comment: Please elaborate, in my example two_digit_list[0] does return 52

Comment: Sorry Fredrik, my mistake, it does return 52. Strange enough, the first run, it returns ['00', '16', '52', '36', '13', '55', '40'] but, it returns 52 now! Thanks!

Comment: Great! I added an edit to address the one digit case that I saw you replied to above aswell :)

Answer (score 1):

This is a simple solve to this.

```
yield_list = []
number_list = [5.2,1600,520,3600,13,55,4000]
for number in number_list:
    string = str(number)
    string =string.replace('.', '')
    yield_list.append(string[:2])
yield_list
```

Answer (score 1):

There is an error in your logic; your < and > are flipped. This code works:

```
def List_Convert_2_Digit(z):
for i in range(len(z)):
    while(z[i]>100 or z[i]<10):
        if(z[i]>100):
            z[i]=z[i]/10
        else:
            z[i]=z[i]*10
return z
```

Answer (score 1):

Solution that increases/decreases the numbers magnitude until we can get the left two digits:

```
def two_digit_list(lst):
    rv = []
    for item in lst:
        if item < 10:
            item *= 10

        while item > 99:
            item //= 10

        rv.append(int(item))
    return rv
```